# Timer/ActionListener usage

Tags: java, timer, compiler-errors, awt, actionlistener

I guess this is simple but I can't really say what is the error.

```
    final Timer tiempo= new Timer(1000,new ActionListener()) ;
```

The only thing I want is that, a delay of 1000 and an action listener, which I don't understand completely. The thing is that I get always an error. 'Is undefined.'

With the method

```
        final Timer tiempo= new Timer(1000, ActionListener() 
    { 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {   

        }
    };
```

Still get undefined and also tried making an instance before

```
ActionListener actionlistener= new ActionListener();
            final Timer tiempo= new Timer(1000, actionlistener() 
    { 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {   

        }
    };
```

Please explain me, this is very frustrating.

```
Error: ActionListner cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace for the error

Comment: You need to post the exact error message if you want someone to help you.

Comment: never mind, anyone facing this issue might just be the solution you are using a java.util.timer instead of a java.swing.timer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example, you've not "created" a new `ActionListener`

```
final Timer tiempo= new Timer(1000, ActionListener() 
{ 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {   

    }
};
```

It should be `new ActionListener()`

```
final Timer tiempo= new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() 
{ 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {   

    }
};
```

Your second example is wrong for number of reasons...

```
ActionListener actionlistener= new ActionListener(); // This won't compile
// because it is an interface and it requires either a concrete implementation
// or it's method signatures filled out...

// This won't work, because java sees actionlistener() as method, which does not
// exist and the rest of the code does not make sense after it (to the compiler)
final Timer tiempo= new Timer(1000, actionlistener() 
{ 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {   

    }
};
```

It should look more like...

```
ActionListener actionlistener= new ActionListener()
{ 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {   

    }
}; 
final Timer tiempo= new Timer(1000, actionlistener);
```

Comment: I tried that one also but gets more confusing for me, I get an error and a warning. first the warning under the Timer(1000, ...) The serializable class  does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long and also The method ActionListener() is undefined for the type xwing (xwing is my main class)

Comment: @xikhari Sounds like you're using Eclipse, I believe you can ignore that particular warning (not an Eclipse user)

Comment: yes ecplise ok thanks was worried about it, and what about the error that is bugging me a lot forget about it sorry really. I was missing the new again thanks really

Comment: Okay, you read the answer right?  The second half?  Where I stated that `actionlistener()` is being seen by the compiler as a method (which doesn't exist) and then the solution under it...?